# Improve sql query speed

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

I have the following sql which takes a long time to execute, are there any better way of writing this to improve speed.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

```
    SELECT a.KeyField
    FROM Details a,
         Master b
    WHERE a.ForeignKeyField = b.ForeignKeyField
      AND a.KeyField IS NOT NULL
      AND Date BETWEEN 
TO_DATE ('01-01-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND TO_DATE ('31-12-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
      AND a.KeyField IN
        (SELECT p.KeyField
         FROM Details p,
              Master q
         WHERE q.ForeignKeyField = p.ForeignKeyField
           AND p.KeyField IS NOT NULL
           AND p.KeyField = a.KeyField
           AND q.FKField2 = b.FKField2
         GROUP BY p.KeyField,
                  q.Date HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT q.ForeignKeyField) > 1)
    GROUP BY b.Id,
             b.Name,
             b.ForeignKeyField,
             b.Date,
             a.ForeignKeyField,
             a.SomeOtherField,
             a.KeyField,
             b.EtcEtc
```

Comment: Prefer a JOIN to WHERE for joining tables, and always do `SmallTable INNER JOIN BigTable`.

Comment: @MPelletier great info!  can you please explain why SmallTable INNER JOIN BigTable

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов It's a rule of thumb, but it works most of the time. The DB engine (for any SQL DB, really) will try and match *from* the first table (Small) *to* the second (Big), so it's faster to go one-by-one in the smaller list and look up in the big, than the reverse. That's what I found by experience.

Comment: @MPelletier thank you - why wouldnt the engine just reverse it itself??

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов Probably because it doesn't know what's the smallest table unless it looks at them both (which can be an expensive operation of its own right). They might not even be tables, they could be inner queries or views. Sometimes you just have to nudge that engine in the right direction.

Comment: @MPelletier Using the JOIN syntax is always a good idea, but I disagree with ordering the tables by size, at least in Oracle.  Oracle always looks up the table statistics.  Unless you've got a bad value for `optimizer_max_permutations` or very bad statistics the order of tables shouldn't matter in recent versions.

Comment: @jonearles But would that apply for views and sub queries?

Comment: @MPelletier Yes, that applies to views and sub queries.  There are many ways of giving the optimizer useful information, like statistics and hints, but the table order should almost never matter.  (Unless you use an ORDERED hint, but even then you should probably use a LEADING hint instead.)

Comment: @jonearles Thanks for setting the record straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to learn proper join syntax.  My guess is that Oracle is choosing a suboptimal query path because of the correlated subquery.  Let's change it to a join instead:

```
SELECT a.KeyField
FROM Details a join
 Master b
 on a.ForeignKeyField = b.ForeignKeyField join
 (SELECT p.KeyField, q.Date, q.FKField2
  FROM Details p join
       Master q
       on q.ForeignKeyField = p.ForeignKeyField
  WHERE p.KeyField IS NOT NULL AND
        q.FKField2 = b.FKField2
  GROUP BY p.KeyField, q.Date
  HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT q.ForeignKeyField) > 1
 ) t
 on a.KeyField = t.KeyField and
    b.FKField2 = t.FKField2
WHERE a.KeyField IS NOT NULL AND
  Date BETWEEN TO_DATE ('01-01-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND TO_DATE ('31-12-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND
GROUP BY b.Id, b.Name, b.ForeignKeyField, b.Date, a.ForeignKeyField, a.SomeOtherField, a.KeyField, 
     b.EtcEtc
```

Writing it this way also makes me realize that there is no condition on the Date, although that is used in the subquery.  Is this correct?

Comment: Date time is used in outer query as I have the condition `entry_date BETWEEN`

Comment: Having JOIN instead of where has increased the speed, I will do a thorough test tomorrow for the results. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When I did a small test I have noticed that there are a lot of rows got retrieved with the query. Is this because when I executed I removed sh_status_code part from the query? I will be doing a thorough test though.

Answer (score 1):

run an `EXPLAIN` on your query, and you will see where the slowness is coming from. However, in general if you can avoid nested queries (your `IN` statement) and `DISTINCT` your queries will perform better. See if you can get away with joining the `Details` and `Master` tables twice within the same query and place indexes accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the relevant indices in place. Check the execution plan to verify that they are actually being used. Oracle is quite picky when it comes to choosing an index.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand the reason for the inner query. i would simplify like this:

```
SELECT a.KeyField
FROM Details a,
     Master b
WHERE a.ForeignKeyField = b.ForeignKeyField
  AND a.KeyField IS NOT NULL
  AND Date >= TO_DATE ('01-01-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
  AND Date <= TO_DATE ('31-12-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy')

GROUP BY b.Id,
         b.Name,
         b.ForeignKeyField,
         b.Date,
         a.ForeignKeyField,
         a.SomeOtherField,
         a.KeyField,
         b.EtcEtc
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT q.ForeignKeyField) > 1
```

also replacing  `BETWEEN` with `>=, <=` will help

Comment: Do not encourage the sql antipattern of implicit joins

Comment: can you explain what antipattern?

Comment: btw i have huge respect for you for the following reasons: 1. you have helped in the past enormously, 2. you are not afraid of asking questions (even though other users with high points are), 3. you do not have a ghost account that you use to hide your downvoted answers unlike the other high-profile users

Comment: implicit joins are easy to get incorrect and have accidental cross joins, they are also more difficult to maintain especially if you later need to change to outer joins as implict and explicit joins shoudl not be mixed. For more information read Bill Karwin's excellent book: http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557/ref=sr_1_cc_1?s=aps&ie=UTF8&qid=1338318559&sr=1-1-catcorr

Comment: `BETWEEN` is not always the evil monster we think it is. Normally the DB engine should be able to go through the table once with between, whereas it will go through table twice with `>=, <=`.